# Log4j on Linux server

Tags: java, log4j

I have Linux server on which I run tomcat with my axis2 webservice.

I use the following for Log4j:
xml configuration file, which is located in the same directory as my webservice java file.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration PUBLIC "-//LOGGER" "log4j.dtd">

<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">

    <!-- Appenders -->
    <appender name="roll" class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <param name="file" value="~//..//tmp//CookTalesLog.log" />
                <param name="append" value="true" />
                <param name="encoding" value="UTF-8" />
                <rollingPolicy class="org.apache.log4j.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
                        <!-- The file to roll to, this is a fairly intelligent parameter, if the file
                        ends in .gz, it gzips it, based on the date stamp it rolls at that time, 
                        default is yyyy-MM-dd, (rolls at midnight)
                        See: http://logging.apache.org/log4j/companions/extras/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/rolling/TimeBasedRollingPolicy.html -->
                        <param name="FileNamePattern" value="CookTalesLog.%d.log.gz" />
                </rollingPolicy>

                <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
                        <!-- The log message pattern -->
                        <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%5p %d{ISO8601} [%t][%x] %c - %m%n" />
                </layout>
    </appender>

    <root>
        <priority value="debug" />
        <appender-ref ref="roll" />
    </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

In the java code:
I tried to use each of the following lines

```
private static final Logger sLogObj = Logger.getLogger( ICDBWebService.class );

private static final Log sLogObj = LogFactory.getLog(ICDBWebService.class);
```

also used:

```
static
{
    DOMConfigurator.configure( "log4j.xml" );
}
```

For logging:

```
    sLogObj.debug( "Login: email=" + email + " pwd= " + password );
```

Log file is not created....

Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The double '//' may be a problem.

You can enable the internal debug output of Log4J by passing `-Dlog4j.debug=true` to the JVM or if running on Tomcat`export TOMCAT_OPTS="-Dlog4j.debug=true` to see what's happening inside Log4J.

Comment: Now it seems that it does not find the log4j.xml Where should it be located?

Comment: The easiest way is to place it into default package of your application. You may use the JVM  System.property `log4j.configuration` (`-Dlog4j.configuration=foobar.xml`) to tell Log4J which configuration file to use.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a simpler file path? Instead of the tilde and double-slashes you have in there at the moment, try just using something like `/tmp/CookTalesLog.log` and see if that helps. It could be simply that the file name doesn't expand properly so it can't be created. Is there anything in the Tomcat logs to suggest a problem?

Answer (score 0):

Use the following to load xml file in your java code:

```
 DOMConfigurator.configureAndWatch("log4jConfigFile.xml");
 private static final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(ICDBWebService.class);
```